# Using a constantly changing downloaded file python?

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Hello everyone I've got my program that navigates to a webpage and clicks a link to download the pdf document I need. But I want to know if there's a way to name this file for python to use and upload it to my google drive. I don't want to manually type the upload file name as it will change every time I click a different download link that I need. So for example the current file is **invoice_sample-1234** but the next download would be **invoice_sample-5678**.

How do I cut out the process of typing each invoice?

Thank you for any help

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get("myurl.com")

window_before = driver.window_handles[0]
driver.find_element(By.ID, "Invoice_Links").click()
window_after = driver.window_handles[1]
driver.switch_to.window(window_after)
download_button= wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID,"Download Doc"))).click()

def upload_Drive():
 upload_file_list = ['invoice_sample-1234.pdf']
   for upload_file in upload_file_list:
    gfile = drive.CreateFile({'parents': [{'id':'Folder' }]})
    gfile.SetContentFile(upload_file)
    gfile.Upload() #Upload the file.
print('file Uploaded')

upload_Drive()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try a random number generator or use timestamp to name it as a file. The file name is a string, like if i try with following pseudo code -

filename =random(seed).toString() + ".pdf"

I think this should work.